# Finding the difference between 2 times in minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a helper function that finds the difference between two times in minutes. But I'm getting stuck on finding the difference between "toLocaleString()" values. Here's what I have so far:

```
  format_time: (date) => {
    var futureTime = new Date(date.getTime() + 15 * 60000).toLocaleString();
    var currentTime = date.toLocaleString();
    return // futureTime - CurrentTime;
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More simple with `getTime()` that represents the epoch time in milliseconds. So in that context, the minutes will be:

1 minute = 60 seconds =  60 0000 milliseconds

your code can be:

```
function diffMinutes(date1, date2) {
    const d1 = new Date(date1).getTime();
    const d2 = new Date(date2).getTime();
    return Math.round((d2 - d1) / 60000); // Can use Math.floor or Math.ceil depends up to you
}
```

The code handles negative values if the second time is lower than the first, so if you want always positive values you can do:

```
    return Math.abs(Math.round((d2 - d1) / 60000));
```

Examples:

```
diffMinutes("01-01-2012 11:11:11", "01-01-2012 11:15:11") // 4
diffMinutes(new Date("01-01-2012 11:11:11"), "01-01-2012 11:00:11") // -11
diffMinutes(12323, 123213) // 2
```

If you know always you call "format_date" the params will be both `Date` object you can reduce your function to:

```
function diffMinutes(date1, date2) {
    return Math.round((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 60000); // Can use Math.floor or Math.ceil depends up to you
}
```

Comment: great work, exactly what i am looking for

Comment: this works with dates but what about times like op asked ? I just get NaN from this

Comment: @Jaxx0rr could you give me the params to get `NaN`? You will get a `NaN` if you send an invalid "time/date" format to `Date` object

Answer (score 0):

if date is string, covert string to timestamp

`new Date("2020/12/24 11:47:03").getTime();`

calculate with timestamp.

`return futureTimestamp - currentTimestamp`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function diffMinutes(x, y) {
  return (y.getTime() - x.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
}

var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
a.setHours(1);
b.setHours(2);

let minutes = diffMinutes(a, b);
console.log('Diff', minutes + 'minutes');
```